# Is "the woman + are" is correct?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I learn English [here](http://www.ef.co.id/englishfirst/englishstudy/soal-toefl-dan-penyelesaiannya-bag-pertama.aspx), but I think the answer is wrong.

> The women aren’t ever received law degrees as today.

Why the correct answer is that?

Why the women using "are" instead of "isn't"?

Comment: This sentence makes no sense to me. However, the answer to the last question is that : _'women'_ is the plural for _'woman'_, and we use _'are'_ instead of _'is'_ for plurals.

Comment: Beyond that, if you're going to say "the women ____ ever received", it looks like the present perfect tense, which uses **have**, so it would be "the women **haven't** ever received".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Google translates the page into English (from Indonesian), the translated page says the sentence you ask about is wrong, and that the correct sentence is

> Never have so many women received law degrees as today.

Which I agree with, as a native speaker of American English.

The sentence

> *The women aren't  ever received law degrees as today.

is NOT correct, which is why I've put an asterisk (*) before it.

You can correct  the verb portion with either of the following options, but as a whole, they're still very questionable  sentences:

> The women aren't ever awarded law degrees as today.

and

> The women have not ever received law degrees as today.

They might work in some contexts, but they aren't very good sentences by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I translated the text around it via Google Translator. It appears to say that that sentence isn't correct.

However, "women are" is not the incorrect part. "woman are" is incorrect, though. You seem to be overlooking that "wom**e**n" is plural, whereas "wom**a**n" is singular. So it's "woman is" and "women are".

Answer (score -2):

“Women” is the plural form except for broadcast media (e.g., tv news), who have their own grammatical rules and lexicon. One rule is they use both the singular and plural forms of words to mean more than one. Sometimes they drop the “s” for whatever reason. Similarly, they will say “several woman are in that space this past week ahead of the conference” (translation: “several women were there last week before the conference”).